# Oracle - Output number of rows affected from dynamic merge statement

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

I have a dynamic sql in a stored procedure with a `MERGE` statement and and executing it using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE <dynamic_sql>`. When I run the merge query through the sql worksheet, it tells me the number of rows merged. How do I retrieve the same information through a dynamic sql?

I would appreciate any efforts towards this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After running any SQL statement (static or dynamic), the `SQL%ROWCOUNT` variable will tell you how many rows were affected.

```
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql_stmt;
  l_rows_affected := SQL%ROWCOUNT;
```

Comment: Thanks. What data type is the variable to be declared as? And must I print it using DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_rows_affected)?

Comment: @user3224907 - `integer`, `number`, or `pls_integer` should all be valid data types for `l_rows_affected` in the snippet I posted.  You can do whatever you want with the value.  `dbms_output` should be a very lightweight tracing utility-- you should assume that no one will ever see data written there.  If the number of rows merged is important, you should be doing something with the result-- write it to a log table, write it to a log file, return it from the procedure, etc.

Comment: `After running "any" SQL statement...` : Wont work for select queries though, unless you use the `Into` or `Using` clauses with Execute Immediate.